# Save file to location and name defined by user input in C++

Tags: c++, string, file, text, user-input

I am having some issues saving a text file that is created in a console window to a custom location that is defined by a user's input. I want it to take string `filepath` which would be the save location and combine it with the string `filename` which would be the name of the text file which the user chose. Such as this `C:\users\bobbert\desktop\c++.txt` I then want to have a 3rd string which would be the actual text to write to the c++.txt file. Here is my code:

```
cout<<"Please enter a name for your file: "<<endl;
cin>>filename;

cout<<"Please enter a directory to save your file in: "<<endl;
cin>>filepath;

//user is now typing data into the text file
cin>>data;
//the data is now being grabbed and put into the "Data" string

FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen (filepath.c_str() + filename.c_str(),"a");

//trying to combine the users selected directory + the selected filename here

if (pFile!=NULL)
{
    fputs(data.c_str(), pFile);
    //here i am trying to take the data of the .txt file
    //string and put it into the new file
}

fclose (pFile);
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this! :)

Comment: For future reference, it would be best if you actually describe what's wrong. You never asked a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In true c++ spirit

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string filename, filepath, data;

    std::cout << "Please enter a name for your file: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> filename;

    std::cout <<" Please enter a directory to save your file in: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> filepath;

    std::ofstream file((filepath + "/" + filename).c_str());

    //std input is being copied to the file
    file << std::cin.rdbuf();
    file << std::flush;
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

In C spirit to combine the path

```
{
    char* fspec;
    if (-1 == asprintf(&fspec, "%s/%s", filepath.c_str(), filename.c_str()))
        { perror("asprintf"); return 255; }
    std::cout << fspec << std::endl;
    free(fspec);
}
```

It wasn't exactly clear to me how you would require the input to be handled;
If you prefer you can read it to a memory buffer using string streams in many ways, e.g. 
without losing whitespace:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::cin.rdbuf();

// OR
std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cin) ,
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
        std::streambuf_iterator<char>(ss));
```

.... and a few alternatives which do remove whitespace:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std:: cin),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        std::stream_iterator<std::string>(ss));

bool my_isspace(char c) { return std::isspace(c); } // in namespace scope
std::remove_copy_if(std::istreambuf_iterator<char> (std::cin),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
        std::streambuf_iterator<char>(ss), my_isspace);
```

Comment: Hey, this is great! Just what I was looking for. One problem though, it cuts out the first word every time. For example I type "Hello Sally" in the console, in the text file it displays " Sally". Also I have been using ctrl+C to exit out because enter didn't work (which is good because I need to be able to write more then one line) is there a proper way to exit? Thanks!

Comment: It's not cutting words with my code, see [here](http://codepad.org/yBAgUsBS). I'm pretty sure you left the stray `cin>>data` statement from your old code? Computers have a habit of obeying your commands :) The proper way to exit is EOF (Ctrl-D on UNIX/linux, Ctrl-Z on Windows)

Comment: Of course, I forgot to remove the cin>>data from my old code. Now it works except for the Ctrl-Z thing. It only exits on Ctrl-C for me. Does Ctrl-z work for you? I am on windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: Although I'm sure learning how to tame the windows console keyboard is not your course objective, I just fired up an old Windows VM, and behold: Ctrl-Z works. Try it with `copy con: nul:`. Incidentally, you can try F6 to insert the Ctrl-Z if your keyboard is playing up

Answer (score 5):

`filepath.c_str() + filename.c_str()` does not concatenate the strings, because they are pointers to arrays of characters, not C++ `std::string` objects. You're just [making an attempt at] performing arithmetic on the pointers.

Try:

```
std::string filename, filepath, data;

cout << "Please enter a name for your file: " << endl;
cin >> filename;

cout << "Please enter a directory to save your file in: " << endl;
cin >> filepath;

//user is now typing data into the text file
cin >> data;

//the data is now being grabbed and put into the "Data" string
ofstream fs((filepath + "/" + filename).c_str(), ios_base::app);

//trying to combine the users selected directory + the selected filename here
if (fs)
   fs << data;
```

I've replaced your use of C-style `fopen` with a C++ stream object, fixed your string problem and added a backslash in between `filepath` and `filename` (for safety in case the user doesn't write it).

<sub>Note that you still need to perform `.c_str()` on the `std::string` result of concatenation when passing the finished path to `ofstream`'s constructor, because iostreams were designed before the strings library. That's just a nasty C++-ism.</sub>

Comment: +1, but actually he's not performing pointer arithmetic, since pointers can't be summed (that line would probably rise a compilation error).

Comment: @Matteo: Attempting to* :) That he can't is, of course, the source of his problems, and if he could then the problems would merely be slightly harder to spot and debug. BTW we usually say "line", not "row".

Answer (score 0):

Is the user terminating the input string with a backslash?  If not then your path is wrong.